# In Codesandbox, Why cant you make private class fields? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, codesandbox

## Question

For some reason, every time I try to make a private class field in Codesndbox, it shows this:

```
`SyntaxError: /Binary.js: Unexpected character '#' (7:2)`

### SyntaxError ###
**/Binary.js: Unexpected character '#' (7:2)**

>#privateMethod() {...
 ^
```

**My MWE on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/question-private-fields-vxw1j?file=/package.json**

What is Wrong!!!

## Extra Data

**Browser:** *Chrome*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

## Answer

1. Open you Sandbox
2. Click the Setting icon not the left side of the screen
3. Scroll down until you find the ".babelrc" file and click Create. (You may have to make a [Sandbox-Github Repo](https://codesandbox.io/docs/git))
4. Now close The file and click the page icon to get back to the file explore (Above the Setting icon)
5. Scroll down until you find the "dependencies" window
6. Go to the search bar and Copy and Past this into it **@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods**
7. once you do that Some options should show up, Click the first one
8. Now Scroll back up and find the ".babelrc" file and click it
9. Now you should see a JSON file open up, Scroll down till you see this:

```json
"plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ],
```

10. Now Copy This:

```json
"plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
  ],
```

and Past it on top of the Plugins array. the File Should look like this now:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
  ],
  "parserOpts": {
    "plugins": [
      "dynamicImport"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now It Should Work!!